# NSWorkspace iconForFile: how to detect the generic folder icon?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am querying some existing folder's icon. 
I am trying to do:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:targetPath]
```

and for the generic icon I am getting:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x6080004533b0>(
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x608000093c90 iconRef=0x405 size:128x128 pixels:128x128>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x608000283ed0 iconRef=0x405 size:128x128 pixels:256x256>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x608000096580 iconRef=0x405 size:256x256 pixels:256x256>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x60800009d290 iconRef=0x405 size:256x256 pixels:512x512>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x60800028d6b0 iconRef=0x405 size:512x512 pixels:512x512>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x60800028e4c0 iconRef=0x405 size:48x48 pixels:48x48>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x60800028da70 iconRef=0x405 size:36x36 pixels:36x36>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x60800028eb50 iconRef=0x405 size:36x36 pixels:72x72>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x60800028f820 iconRef=0x405 size:32x32 pixels:32x32>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x60800028f6e0 iconRef=0x405 size:32x32 pixels:64x64>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x60800028f780 iconRef=0x405 size:18x18 pixels:18x18>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x60800028bdb0 iconRef=0x405 size:18x18 pixels:36x36>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x60800028f7d0 iconRef=0x405 size:16x16 pixels:16x16>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x608000285a50 iconRef=0x405 size:16x16 pixels:32x32>,
<NSIconRefImageRep:0x608000080b90 iconRef=0x405 size:512x512 pixels:1024x1024>
)
```

How can I distinguish whether a folder has the regular "generic" icon, or a custom made one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folder icons are stored within the folder in an invisible file named "Icon\r". So an easy way to check this is like this:

```
func folderHasCustomIcon(path: String) -> Bool {
    let iconPath = NSString.pathWithComponents([path, "Icon\r"])
    return NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(iconPath)
}

folderHasCustomIcon("/Users/stefan/Desktop/foo") // true
folderHasCustomIcon("/Users/stefan/Desktop/bar") // false
```

Both `~/Desktop/foo` and `~/Desktop/bar` exist. I have given `foo` a custom icon using the Finder's *File Info* window.